# What is the differnce between these two types using jquery

Tags: jquery

```
$('tr td:first-child').click(function() {
            var foobar = $(this).text();
            $("#showgrid").load('/Product/List/Item?id=' + foobar);
        });
```

When I am sending foobar value like this in the Actionresult method I am getting string id value perfectly but I am not able to display the grid?

But interesting thing is when I am sending like this

```
 $("#showgrid").load('/Product/List/Item?id=' + "12345");
```

Then I am able to display the grid. foobar result is same 12345.

What is the different between these two types?

Comment: What happens if you do `alert(foobar);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var foobar = $.trim($(this).text());
```

You may have some extra spaces in there.

Comment: Yes the problem with Spaces thanks for lettingme know. 
I appreciate that.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

From the docs: text() returns the *combined text contents of each element in the set of matched elements, including their descendants.* So, if you have any other nodes that contain text in the first-child of the td, it'll include that text as well. Can you post some markup so we can see what you are targeting?